# Posibility to mock delay?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, redux-observable

I'm performing a epic test. Problem? I use delay. See

```
export const displayToasterEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(SHOW_TOASTER)
    .filter(action => action.toaster.show)
    .delay(getToaster(store.getState()).duration || DELAY_TOASTER)
    .map(() => showToaster(MESSAGE_CLOSE));
```

My test:

```
  describe('displayToasterEpic', () => {
    it('should display toaster delete account', () => {
      const expectedAction1 = {
        type: SHOW_TOASTER,
        toaster: MESSAGE_DELETE_ACCOUNT,
      };
      const expectedAction2 = {
        type: SHOW_TOASTER,
        toaster: MESSAGE_CLOSE,
      };

      store = mockStore(displayToasterEpic);

      store.dispatch(expectedAction1);

      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([expectedAction1, expectedAction2]);
    });
```

The probleme is this delay. Same problem when `jest.clearAllTimers();`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWRj4.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used`jest.useFakeTimers()` when using `jest.runAllTimers();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find myself a pretty solution to mock delay. Used the method spyOn :)